# babel package and lstlisting caption incompatibility

Tags: listings, languages, babel, naming

I am using `babel` package for **Turkish** language and I also use `listings` package. A code sample for one of my listings is as follows:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label=some-code,caption=Poo Class]
public class Person {

    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }

}
\end{lstlisting}
```

As header, what I am getting is this:

> Listing 7.1: Poo Class

I would like it to be like this:

> Kod Örneği 7.1: Poo Class

Am I asking too much?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Redefine `\lstlistingname`:

```
\renewcommand\lstlistingname{New name}
```