# Change language of caption in lstlisting

Tags: listings, captions, languages

When I define a caption in `lstlisting`, LaTeX writes, for example, "Listing 1.1: ..." but I want to change the "Listing" to another language. How can I do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! If you need the new name for a language only, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34400/babel-package-and-lstlisting-caption-incompatibility If that doesn't work, then please add why to your question.

Comment: So we'll close this question as a duplicate. Don't worry about it and be again welcome!